# `text-property-not-all` doesn't seem to work as documented

Tags: text-properties

Why I get 1 instead of nil for following function? Am I misunderstanding how text property searching works?

```
(defun set-properties()
  (interactive)
  (add-text-properties 1 6 '(test "em"))
  (message (format "%s" (text-property-not-all 1 6 'test "em"))))
```

Yet, this function prints `"em"` as it should:

```
(defun get-single-property()
  (interactive)
  (message (format "%s" (get-text-property 1 'test))))
```

I was using functions on plain text buffer with 6 letters.

Answer (score 2):

That's because text-properties are compared with `eq` and

```
(eq "em" "em")
```

is `nil` because those two strings are different heap objects.

`C-h f text-property-not-all` says:

> **`text-property-not-all`** is a built-in function in `C source code`.
>
> `(text-property-not-all START END PROPERTY VALUE &optional OBJECT)`
>
> Check text from `START` to `END` for property `PROPERTY` not equaling `VALUE`.
>
> If so, return the position of the first character whose property `PROPERTY`
>   is **not `eq` to `VALUE`**.  Otherwise, return `nil`.
>
> If the optional fifth argument `OBJECT` is a buffer (or `nil`, which means
>   the current buffer), `START` and `END` are buffer positions (integers or
>   markers).  If `OBJECT` is a string, `START` and `END` are 0-based indices into it.

If you insist on using a string, you should either use something else than `text-property-not-all`, or make sure you really use the exact same string object.  For example:

```
(defconst my-test-value "em")
(defun set-properties ()
  (interactive)
  (add-text-properties 1 6 `(test ,my-test-value))
  (message (format "%s" (text-property-not-all 1 6 'test my-test-value))))
```

Comment: (`text-property-not-all` could be enhanced to accept an optional `TEST` arg. A more useful example might be a property value that is a cons or other non-symbol sexp - `equal` might be a reasonable `TEST` predicate for some such cases.)